# Material UI how to justify content inside FormControlLabel

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to align the label and the radio button inside a `FormControlLabel` component so that the label consumes the same width regardless of the text inside of it. Here's what it currently looks like:

[image]

Here's the code I have:

```
<RadioGroup row>

    <FormControl>
      <FormControlLabel
        value={first_column_day}
        control={
          <Radio
            value={first_column_day}
          />
        }
        label={<Typography variant={"subtitle2"}>{first_column_day}</Typography>}
        labelPlacement="start"
      />
    </FormControl>

    <FormControl>
      <FormControlLabel
        value={second_column_day}
        control={
          <Radio
            value={second_column_day}
          />
        }
        label={<Typography variant={"subtitle2"}>{second_column_day}</Typography>}
        labelPlacement="start"
      />
    </FormControl>

</RadioGroup>
```

I tried adding `justifyContent` for `FormControl`:

```
<FormControl style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
```

I also tried wrapping `Typography` in a `div`:

```
<div><Typography variant={"subtitle2"}>{first_column_day}</Typography></div>
```

But those didn't work. So far the only thing that worked is adding a fixed width to the `Typography` like so:

```
<Typography style={{ width: 75 }} variant={"subtitle2"}>{first_column_day}</Typography>
```

But I don't really like doing that because it's not responsive. Setting the width to 100% doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `min-width` to `FormControlLabel` component if you need alignment like below without losing responsiveness  -

[image]

Working Sandbox here - https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-3u8i2?file=/demo.js